# Inserir link automático em hashtags

Tags: php

Eu preciso de um sistema que identifica a palavra com o # dentro de um texto e adiciona em uma tabela.

E outro sistema que identifica a palavra com # dentro de um texto, porém, na hora de aparecer na div, a palavra seja linkada.

Exemplo de texto inicial:

> O pessoal do #Stackoverflow são ótimos em #programação.

Ele transforma em:

> O pessoal do [#Stackoverflow](http://meusite.com/hashtag/Stackoverflow) são ótimos em [#programação](http://meusite.com/hashtag/programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o alvo são apenas os acentos comuns em português, fica fácil listá-los um a um. Eu faria uma regex com os seguintes blocos:

- `A-Za-z` maiúsculas e minúsculas sem acento
- `áàâãéèêíïóôõöúç`ñ: vogais acentuadas do português, cedilha e umas outras de lambuja, minúsculas
- `ÁÀÂÃÉÈÊÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ`: vogais acentuadas do português, cedilha e umas outras de lambuja, maiúsculas
  espaços

Portanto:

```
/^[A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]+$/
```

Ou, deixando a distinção minúsculas/maiúsculas para a implementação:

```
/^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ ]+$/i
```

Portanto para utilizar com 0-9, a-z, A-Z e com acentos:

```
<?php
    $text = "O pessoal do #Stackoverflow são ótimos em #programação.";
    $text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-ZáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ_]+)/', '<a href="http://meusite.com/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>', $text);
    echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: Por que o espaço no final do grupo das regex?

Comment: Aê, deu certo! Obrigado.

Comment: @EGDEV O Código ocorreu corretamente, porém está com erro de acento. Como eu removo ele?

Comment: Poderia informar o erro?